# Error xss AWS WAF CrossSiteScripting_BODY in my request

Tags: html, rest, xss, amazon-waf

I need to send some information to an API, in one of the fields the information is contained in an HTML so that the message contains some style editing, and I am getting a 403 CrossSiteScripting_BODY error.

I shouldn't disable this CrossSiteScripting_BODY check and I need to send this information as HTML. Would it be possible for me to put some parameter in the HTML that I am sending so that an attack attempt does not occur?

For example: `<div xss-remove>Test</div>`

My Request :

```
{
  id: 1,
  description: "<b>Test</b><div style=\"text-align: center;\">TestTest;</div>"
}
```

Response:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too
much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to
EVIDÊNCIA DE TESTES
troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 9UXcrNUxCQ7qsbNC9xGzCiG-a44RDKDBVv4p4NYtWvVwDaMoTjF0Iw==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML> ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot use
'in' operator to search for 'detailedMessage' in <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too
much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
```

- Switching to base_64 is not an option